# How do I call an asynchronous process from an asp.net hosted module using C#5 async / await?

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, c#-5.0, nancy, async-await

I have a long running process that is called via a Nancy Module Get method. Rather than have the browser hang while the process runs I would like this call to be asynchronous, in other words I want the Get method to return right away and leave the long running process to do its thing. I could then check the status of the process at regular intervals and act accordingly.

I am new to the async / await features of C#5 but I feel sure these are meant for just this kind of task. The code below shows my attempt. I have put in some Logging that demonstrates that it is not running asynchronously as expected. Instead the long running process blocks the Get method and so the browser hangs.

**Module**

```
public class TestModule : NancyModule
{            
    public TestModule(ITestService testService)
    {
        Get["/longprocess"] = _ =>
            {
                Log.Write("Module : Start");
                testService.LongProcess();
                Log.Write("Module : Finish");
                return HttpStatusCode.OK;
            };
    }
}
```

**Service**

```
public interface ITestService
{
    Task<bool> LongProcess();
}

public class TestService : ITestService
{
    public async Task<bool> LongProcess()
    {
        await LongProcessAsynch();
        return true;
    }

    private Task<bool> LongProcessAsynch()
    {
        Log.Write("LongProcess : Start");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        //Task.Delay(5000); <- Has same effect
        Log.Write("LongProcess : Finish");
        return true.AsTask();
    }
}
```

**Extension Method**

```
public static Task<T> AsTask<T>(this T candidate)
{
    var source = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
    source.SetResult(candidate);
    return source.Task;
}
```

**Log Output**

```
14/06/2012 19:22:29 : Module : Start
14/06/2012 19:22:29 : LongProcess : Start
14/06/2012 19:22:34 : LongProcess : Finish
14/06/2012 19:22:34 : Module : Finish
```

You can see from the Log Output above that the `LongProcess()` is blocking the return of the Get module. If the task was running asynchronously I would expect the log to look something like this:

**Expected Log**

```
Module : Start
LongProcess : Start
Module : Finish
LongProcess : Finish
```

I think what is actually required is to put the `await` in the NancyModule Get method. Something like the code below perhaps, but I cannot do this because I cannot mark the module constructor as `asnyc` and so I cannot use `await` within the Get method (or so I currently believe)

```
Get["/longprocess"] = _ =>
    {
        Log.Write("Module : Start");
        await testService.LongProcess();
        Log.Write("Module : Finish");
        return HttpStatusCode.OK;
    };
```

Thanks for any help, examples or pointers to resources.

**Edit 1**

More research reveals that asp.net seems to actively prevent `async` calls by default. Something to do with the `Session` and the way it processes non UI threads I believe. So I have added the following to my web.config (see below)

- UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext
- enableSessionState="false"

Unfortunately it does not make any difference and my `async` / `await` call to `LongProcess()` is still blocking.

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    <add key="webPages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" enableSessionState="false" />
    ... more config
</configuration>
```

Comment: I don't know what NancyFX is but it needs to support Tasks as return values for you to make use of it asynchronously.

Comment: I have nested the async call to try and get around this. The initial call to `testService.LongProcess()` is synchronous but this then calls the `LongProcessAsynch()` method using the `await` keyword and so this should be asynchronous. Do you think this is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am new to the async / await features of C#5 but I feel sure these are meant for just this kind of task.

No. `async`/`await` are intended to make asynchronous programming easy *within the context of a single process*. They do not change the nature of HTTP communications.

When you use `await` on an ASP.NET server (in the context of an HTTP request), you are returning the ASP.NET thread to the thread pool. However, ASP.NET is aware that the HTTP request has not completed, so it does not complete the response to the client (browser).

This is by design.

You'll need to use AJAX, SignalR, or some other solution in order to do what you want.

Comment: I am currently using jQuery $.ajax() to make my an async call to my api. Of course this is not really async since asp.net blocks the response as you describe. So my only option is to spin off on a new thread and return an id? That will surely work but I want to double check that I cannot use the new async features given the config attrib `UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext`? Sorry to re-iterate my question but I want to be sure before I go off and do an old-school thread-ache solution.

Comment: You don't want to spin off a new thread (this is almost always a mistake on ASP.NET; consider recycling). Take a step back and examine your requirements. You want to issue a command that will start a workflow. Web servers were not designed for this; you really should persist it somehow (e.g., MSMQ/Azure Queues) or pass it off to another server (e.g., Win32 service).

Comment: OK, I accept that I am barking up the wrong tree here so I will take a good look at what I am trying to achieve and see if it can be done with a simpler approach. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

try setting the page attribute `Async="true"`in the aspx page
after doing that it wold look like this 
   `<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="XXX.aspx.cs" Inherits="xxx" Async="true" %>`

the in tcode behile file you can make the tasks and methods of type async and  calll `await`  tasks from them ...

it might work