# Can I use async / await in an asp.net hosted RESTful API?

Tags: asp.net, c#-5.0, async-await

Is it possible to have have asynchronous calls to a RESTful API hosted under asp.net?

I have a long running process. I want to trigger it to start via an http GET request and then check on its progress periodically. How do I do this using the new C#5 `async` / `await` syntax?

I have a detailed example in this question:

- [How do I call an asynchronous process from an asp.net hosted module using C#5 async / await?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039411/how-do-i-call-an-asynchronous-process-from-an-asp-net-hosted-module-using-c5-as)

Comment: How do you intend to report progress from your API? Even if the call is asynchronous from the client you need to implement progress reporting at your API level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need to use await or async. Maybe you can start a new thread to run the long time task, and return a task id to the client immediately. And the client use this id to check the progress of the task.